# Django Model Inheritance - Instance attributes not set properly

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

Alas, my code was working perfect until I decided to "fix" it using inheritance for linked classes.

I have a `UserProgram` class that inherits from `Program` and `MyUser`.  When I changed the class definition to `UserProgram(Program, MyUser)`, I started getting strange behavior with my `UserProgram.objects.get()` call, which gets its data from a stored procedure via `get_data_pk()`:

`raw('select 1 as id, * from SP_GetUserProgram(%s,%s,%s)', params)`

[image]

After adding the inheritance, I see the new objects have all the inherited fields, but the attributes are not being assigned the correct values now.  For instance, `maxbudget` and `availablebudget` should both be `400000`, but that is incorrectly assigned to `uploaddirectoryid` and `is_active`.

[image]

Creating the `UserProgram` objects manually via `UserProgram(...)` works fine, but not via the DB call anymore.  I'm not sure what's going on.  Any ideas?  Here's a simplified version of my code.

**models.py**

```py
class UserProgramManager(models.Manager):
    def get(self, userid, programname, schoolyear):
        return get_data_pk(self, 
          'SP_GetUserProgram(%s,%s,%s)', (userid, programname, schoolyear)
        )

class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        abstract = True

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    userid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    objects = MyUserManager()

class Program(MyModel):
    programname = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    schoolyear = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __init__(self,schoolyear=None,programname=None,*args,**kwargs):
        super(Program, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.schoolyear = schoolyear
        self.programname = programname

        # Do some extra processing (not included here)

class UserProgram(Program, MyUser):
    uploaddirectoryid = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    objects = UserProgramManager()
```

**test.py**

```
# Works fine
myuserprogram = UserProgram(
  userid=17,
  schoolyear=2020,
  programname='incentive'
)

# Attributes are not set correctly
myuserprogram = UserProgram.objects.get(
  userid=17,
  schoolyear=2020,
  programname='incentive'
)
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do. First of all Program model should not override __init__ in the way you do this. The fields defined on model itself are enough to be able to instantiate it. Second of all - in your `test.py` snippet on first line you are not creating an entry inside DB!  this is just creating object instance. While on second line you seem to try fetch it from DB.

Comment: Thanks amigo, that helped me look in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the words of Homer Simpson: I am so smart.  S...M...R...T.

It looks like my `__init__` functions were causing the problems.  I removed the named parameters and just left `*args, **kwargs` and it works fine:

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
  super(Program, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```